# Creating a for if loop with custom range

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm trying to create a script checking the A column with row 8,9,10,11,12,13, SKIPPING 14, 15,16,17,18, SKIPPING 19, 20,21,22. If it is empty I would like to hide that row.

Is there a way to define the range of rows before the if statement?

This is what I have, but I need to do a seperate loop every time there is a gap in rows

```
 for (i = 8; i < 14; i++) {  //for loop for Current rep
    if (sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == "") { 
    sheet.hideRows(i)};  
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hideRows(){
  const rowsToCheck = [
    "8:13",
    "19:22"
    // add additional row ranges in the form from:to
  ]
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  for(rows of rowsToCheck){
    const [from,to] = rows.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/).slice(1).map(x=>Number(x))
    for(let row=from; row<=to; row+=1){
      sheet.hideRows(row)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the rows you want to skip before the `if`, but you can also add an additional condition to check:

```
for (i = 8; i <= 22; i++) { 
   if ((i != 14 || i != 19) && sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == "")
      sheet.hideRows(i);
}
```

Therefore, the `hideRows` method will only execute when the row number is different than `14` **or** `19` **and** the value corresponding to the `(i,1)` range is empty.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great concise spin on the problem!

Answer (score 1):

And you can always specify the rows directly. This way:

```
var rows = [8,9,10,11,12,13,19,20,21,22];

for (row of rows) if (sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == "") sheet.hideRows(i)
```

But I'd advice you to use `getValues()` to get an array and check the array instead:

```
var rows = [8,9,10,11,12,13,19,20,21,22];

var data = sheet.getRange(8,1,22,1).getValues(); // get all cells at once

for (row of rows) if (data[row-1][0] == "") sheet.hideRows(row) // check the array
```

It will work faster.

Comment: Thanks, this is very easy to understand